# How to pass a parameter from a SQL Server Agent Job to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have a stored procedure that I need to run for multiple locations. I have added a parameter in it for the LocationID, which is a string. I need help setting up a job step which passes it a location ID and outputs it to a path. Below is a screenshot of what I have tried and it did not work.

[This is what I tried:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsH3K.png)

```
Declare @cmd varchar(5000),
        @LocID = 'NY13'

select @cmd =  'bcp "EXEC ASAP.dbo.usp_Assessments"+ @LocID + queryout  "\\appservices.local\LocalationNY13\NY13.csv" -T -c'

exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Look at the screenshot for a picture of the step.

This is the error I received:

> Incorrect syntax near '='. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@cmd".
>
> [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 137)
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@cmd".
>
> [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 137).  The step failed.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Maybe I am not choosing the right option maybe I need to go about this another way?

Comment: `Declare @cmd varchar(5000), @LocID = 'NY13'` is simply not a valid statement -- `@LocID` has no type.

Comment: Made the correction... it runs but no output now.